# Content entity doesn't load on edit

Tags: 8, entities

I have a custom entity, `BaseEstablishment` which is an abstract base class, implemented by `Practice`.

```
abstract class BaseEstablishment extends ContentEntityBase implements EntityOwnerInterface {
    // The necessary functions required for get/set methods
    // The baseFieldDefinitions method
    public static function baseFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
        $fields = parent::baseFieldDefinitions($entity_type);
        // Standard field, used as unique if primary index.
        $fields['id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('integer')
              ->setLabel(t('ID'))
              ->setDescription(t('The ID of the entity.'))
              ->setReadOnly(TRUE);
        // Standard field, unique outside of the scope of the current project.
        $fields['uuid'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('uuid')
              ->setLabel(t('UUID'))
              ->setDescription(t('The UUID of the entity.'))
              ->setReadOnly(TRUE);
       /*=====================================================*/
       // Name field for the establishment (vc 256)
       $fields['name'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
          ->setLabel(t('Name'))
          ->setDescription(t('Name of the establishment.'))
          ->setRequired(TRUE)
          ->setSettings([
                  'default_value' => '',
                  'max_length' => 256,
                  'text_processing' => 0,
          ])
          ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
                'label' => 'above',
                'type' => 'string',
                'weight' => -5,
          ])
          ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
                'type' => 'string_textfield',
                'weight' => -5,
          ])
          ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
          ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
        $fields['affiliated_users'] = 

        BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
          ->setLabel(t('Affiliated Users'))
          ->setDescription(t('The users allowed to manage this     establishment.'))
          ->setRevisionable(FALSE)
          ->setRequired(FALSE)
          ->setSettings([
                  'target_type' => 'user',
                  'default_value' => 0,
                ]
              )
          ->setCardinality(-1)
          ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
                'label' => 'hidden',
                'type' => 'author',
                'weight' => 0,
          ]);
    // Rest of fields that I need
    return $fields;
    }
}

/**
* Defines the practice entity class.
*
* There are many more properties to be used in an entity type definition. For
* a complete overview, please refer to the '\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityType'
* class definition.
*
* @ingroup practice
*
* @ContentEntityType(
*   id = "myentity_practice",
*   label = @Translation("Practice"),
*   label_collection = @Translation("Practice"),
*   label_singular = @Translation("Practice"),
*   label_plural = @Translation("Practices"),
*   label_count = @PluralTranslation(
*     singular = "@count practice",
*     plural = "@count practices"
*   ),
*   handlers = {
*     "view_builder" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder",
*     "list_builder" = "Drupal\myentity\Entity\Controller\PracticeListBuilder",
*     "form" = {
*       "add" = "Drupal\myentity\Entity\Form\PracticeForm",
*       "edit" = "Drupal\myentity\Entity\Form\PracticeForm",
*       "delete" = "Drupal\myentity\Entity\Form\PracticeDeleteForm",
*     },
*   },
*   base_table = "_practice",
*   data_table = "myentity_practice_data",
*   fieldable = FALSE,
*   translatable = FALSE,
*   entity_keys = {
*     "id" = "id",
*     "uuid" = "uuid",
*     "owner" = "uid",
*   },
*   links = {
*     "canonical" = "/practice/{id}",
*     "delete-form" = "/practice/{id}/delete",
*     "edit-form" = "/practice/{id}/edit",
*     "collection" = "/practice/list"
*   },
*   field_ui_base_route = "myentity.admin.entity.practice.main",
* )
*/    
class Practice extends BaseEstablishment implements PracticeInterface {
    // Any changes that are required for the practice entity.
    // The PracticeInterface extends the EstablishmentInterface, 
    // which exposes all the required get/set methods.
    // There aren't many changes that happen here;
    // I've commented out everything in this file
    // and the issue still persists.
}

class PracticeForm extends ContentEntityForm {
    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        $form = parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
        /**
         * This is always null, 
         * regardless of whether it is accessed via: 
         * /practice/add or /practice/{id}/edit
         */
        $entity = $this->entity;

        if (is_null($entity->id()) {
            $form['#title'] = $this->t("Add Practice");
        } else {
            // $entity->getName() is a getter method defined by the practice interface.
            $form['#title'] = $this->t("Edit " . $entity->getName());
        }

        // rest of customization to the form that are dependent upon the conditional above.

        return $form;
    }
}
```

The above is the PHP code that drives the entity. I'm not sure if it's necessary, but the routing file is below:

```
#########################################################
# Practice Admin/User paths
#########################################################
myentity.admin.entity.practice.main:
  path: '/admin/content/practice'
  defaults:
    _entity_list: 'myentity_practice'
    _title: 'Practice List'
  requirements:
    # Checks for permission directly.
    _permission: 'administer site'

myentity.user.entity.practice.form.add:
  path: '/practice/add'
  defaults:
    # Calls the form.add controller, defined in the practice entity.
    _entity_form: 'myentity_practice.add'
    _title: 'Add Practice'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer site'

myentity.user.entity.practice.form.edit:
  path: '/practice/{id}/edit'
  defaults:
    # Calls the form.edit controller, defined in the practice entity.
    _entity_form: 'myentity_practice.edit'
    _title: 'Edit Practice'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer site'
#    _permission: 'authenticated user'

myentity.user.entity.practice.form.delete:
  path: '/practice/{id}/delete'
  defaults:
    # Calls the form.delete controller, defined in the practice entity.
    _entity_form: 'myentity_practice.delete'
    _title: 'Delete Practice'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer site'
```

The problem is that when I add a practice through the form: `/practice/add`, it correctly stores it in the database.  However, when I go to: `practice/1/edit`, the entity is *always* null, I can see it in the database and it is listed on `PracticeListBuilder` page.

As for trying to figure out what the issue is: I've tried minimizing the total fields added -- removing the `EntityOwner` and my custom affiliated users field.  I don't understand why the entity is always null when trying to edit the entity.

Comment: The parameter should be the machine name of the entity, then it will be upcast to an entity object.

Comment: ...alright then.  That's just embarrassing.  If you'd be so kind to add that as an answer, I can give you due credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter should be the machine name of the entity, then it will be upcast to an entity object.